# which directory instead of "Program Files" to manually install for a single user in Windows 11?

Tags: windows, windows-10, windows-11

I'm using Windows 11, and I notice that some application installers give you an option to "install for all users" or "install for one user". With the former but not the latter, a popup for admin permission comes up before you are allowed to proceed. This makes sense.

However, for some installers, it doesn't explicitly give you the option to "install for single user", but instead just allows you to edit the install path.

For example, the Transmission installer currently allows you to edit the path, and by default it is `C:\Program Files\Transmission\`.

If I wanted to install for just one user, what should I replace that path with?

Comment: I have a directory `c:\apps` where I typically install my stuff. It's really down to personal preference.

Comment: In either case the only reason for the elevated permissions is for the creation of the shortcut to the application to your desktop.  So while you can install Transmission wherever you want, it can be executed by any user, who knows it’s installed by going to the installation directory and running the application

Comment: Use any directory you like that is not a sensitive one in Windows.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To install an app for just one user, use `%localappdata%` instead. This path translates to `C:\Users\<username>\appdata\Local` and makes sure all files are only accessible by that user and no admin rights are necessary either.

Many popular apps (Chrome, WhatsApp Desktop, Spotify, etc...) that target for single user installs, all install in either appdata\local or appdata\roaming. Microsoft intended appdata\local to be storage that remains on this computer, which is often programs, whereas roaming is stuff like your settings. When a program offers support for computer wide install (aka all users), then it is likely, that each user can still have their own settings, and the developer could choose between storing this in the registry, but if they also need to store files, its almost always going to be appdata\roaming. Because you don't want the app on a place where the program may also write, using appdata\local is the way to go for installing an app for a single user.

Comment: Note that if the installer isn't aware of what you're trying to do (and it's not, because it doesn't offer this feature by itself) it will still proceed as if the program was installed for all users. Which means that they will get Start menu shortcuts, file associations etc.